# Restructuring a DB for best performance

Tags: mysql, performance, select, join

I need a little help in restructuring my DB so that the following select query will be more efficient. 
The problem is every entry in table `post` has a category column with list separated by comma.

the query

```
SELECT id, short_story, SUBSTRING( full_story, 1, 15 ) AS full_story, xfields, title, category, alt_name, comm_num, allow_comm, allow_rate, 
FIXED , rating, vote_num, news_read, votes, editdate, editor, reason, view_edit, tags
FROM post
LEFT JOIN post_plus ON ( post.id = post_plus.news_id ) 
WHERE category REGEXP '[[:<:]](130|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|21|22|24|25|26|27|29|133|135|125|20|132)[[:>:]]'
AND category REGEXP  '[[:<:]](73)[[:>:]]'
AND approve =1
ORDER BY FIXED DESC , DATE DESC 
LIMIT 98 , 7
```

The list is so long because I've couple of main category with lots of subcategories. currently It's scanning the whole table with a ragexp and searching for the right match. When I check `process list` I see tons of above queries with a status `Creating sort index` and my cpu is in 100% use

explain indicates i'm using the right indexes:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | post      | ref  | approve       | approve | 1       | const              | 9593 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | post_plus | ref  | news_id       | news_id | 5       | online.post.id |    1 | NULL                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

What is the best way to structure a db to handle this task?

Comment: Any regexp matching on a column is going to render any indexing on the table useless, and every query will require a full table scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed yourself, the main issue here is the structure of the category field causing your statement to perform a full table scan everytime it is invoked.

Pull the categories ouf of there into another table, and glue it together with a meta table.

First, create a category table, maybe like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `post_category_meta` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Now create a meta table:

```
CREATE TABLE `post_category_meta` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `meta` (`post_id`,`category_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Now add your categories into the category table and add the relationship in the meta table. Glue them together with a proper `JOIN` your query, done.