# Very slow query with: <derived2> Using temporary; Using filesort

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, performance

I've performance problems with my select category query [Restructuring a DB for best performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677382/restructuring-a-db-for-best-performance)
So I set a goal to fix it. but at the end it turned out to be a much more complex query  and performance actually decreased compared to original query.

```
SELECT *
FROM   post
       LEFT JOIN post_plus
         ON ( post.id = post_plus.news_id )
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT c1.postid
                  FROM   post_category c1
                         JOIN post_category c2
                           ON c1.postid = c2.postid
                  WHERE  c1.categoryid IN ( 130, 3, 4, 5 )
                         AND c2.categoryid = 73) post_category 
         ON ( post_category.postid = post.id ) 
WHERE  approve = 1
ORDER  BY fixed DESC,
          date DESC     
LIMIT  0, 7;
```

the new query takes: (1.02 sec) - 
old query with regexp took (0.23 sec)

I can only guess it's because of the `Using temporary; Using filesort`

How can I get rid of this?

explain query:

```
`+----+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys     | key        | key_len | ref                      | rows  | Extra                                  |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>    | ALL    | NULL              | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                     | 10470 | Using temporary; Using filesort        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | post      | eq_ref | PRIMARY,approve   | PRIMARY    | 4       | post_category.postid |     1 | Using where                            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | post_plus | ref    | news_id           | news_id    | 5       | post_category.postid |     1 | NULL                                   |
|  2 | DERIVED     | c1            | range  | postId,categoryId | categoryId | 2       | NULL                     | 10470 | Using index condition; Using temporary |
|  2 | DERIVED     | c2            | ref    | postId            | postId     | 4       | online_test.c1.postId    |     1 | Using index                            |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+
```

`

post table

```
| post | CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `autor` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `short_story` text NOT NULL,
  `full_story` text NOT NULL,
  `xfields` text NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `descr` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `keywords` text NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `alt_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comm_num` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `allow_comm` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `allow_main` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `approve` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fixed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `allow_br` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `symbol` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `metatitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `FileTempUUID` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `autor` (`autor`),
  KEY `alt_name` (`alt_name`),
  KEY `category` (`category`),
  KEY `allow_main` (`allow_main`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `symbol` (`symbol`),
  KEY `comm_num` (`comm_num`),
  KEY `tags` (`tags`),
  KEY `descr` (`descr`),
  KEY `title` (`title`),
  KEY `approve` (`approve`,`allow_main`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `full_story` (`full_story`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `short_story` (`short_story`,`full_story`,`xfields`,`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title_2` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32586 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

post_plus

```
| post_plus | CREATE TABLE `post_plus` (
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `news_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kp_id` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `pdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `news_read` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `allow_rate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `rating` mediumint(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `vote_num` mediumint(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `votes` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `editdate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `view_edit` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `editor` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `reason` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `access` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `news_id` (`news_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32819 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

post_category table

```
| post_category | CREATE TABLE `post_category` (
  `cid` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categoryId` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY `postId` (`postId`,`categoryId`),
  KEY `categoryId` (`categoryId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100870 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: Really - besides the EXPLAIN plan - you should show all the tables' definitions (output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`) so we know datatypes, primary and foreign keys, indexes.

Comment: Can you add a `(categoryId, postId)` index and update with efficiency and new Explain?

Comment: And why the second `LEFT JOIN` (to the derived table) is a `LEFT` join in the first place? looks like it should be an `INNER` join.

Comment: yes it's inner. copied an old code... i have keys for `  KEY `postId` (`postId`,`categoryId`),
  KEY `categoryId` (`categoryId`)
` in post_category table

Comment: Add one more, composite, index on `(categoryId, postId)` and you can drop the `(categoryId)` one.

Comment: yep that was a little faster `(0.77 sec)`

Comment: Now add an index on `(approve, fixed, date)` and try both your query and @Lawrence's rewrite which looks good.

Comment: One more question: Is every post restricted to one "post_plus" or it can have many? (You have no foreign keys defined so we may guess wrong.)

Comment: only one post_plus per post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this query is equivalent in spirit, and may perform faster. Especially if you create an index on `post_category (postid, categoryid)`

```
Select
    *
From
    post
        Left Join
    post_plus
        On post.id = post_plus.news_id
Where
    Exists (
        Select
            'x'
        From
            post_category c1
        Where
            categoryid = 73 and
            c1.postid = post.postid
    ) And
    Exists (
        Select
            'x'
        From
            post_category c2
        Where
            categoryid In (130, 3, 4, 5) and
            c2.postid = post.postid
    ) And
    approve = 1
Order By
    fixed Desc,
    date Desc
Limit
    0, 7;
```

As `postid, categoryid` is unique on `post_category`, you could also rewrite it like this. It would probably benefit from an index in the reverse order `(categoryid, postid)`:

```
Select
    post.*,
    post_plus.*
From
    post_category c1
        Inner Join
    post
        On c1.categoryid = 73 and c1.postid = post.postid
        Left Join
    post_plus
        On post.id = post_plus.news_id
Where
    Exists (
        Select
            'x'
        From
            post_category c2
        Where
            categoryid In (130, 3, 4, 5) and
            c2.postid = post.postid
    ) And
    approve = 1
Order By
    fixed Desc,
    date Desc
Limit
    0, 7;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there is (maximum) only one post_plus per post, you can limit first and then apply the join to `post_plus`, with either your query or Laurence's rewrite (or any other equivalent). Here's Laurence's query rewritten this way and slightly modified:

```
Select
    p.*, pp.*
From
  ( Select
        post.id
    From
        post
    Where
        Exists (
            Select
                'x'
            From
                post_category As c1
            Where
                c1.categoryid = 73 And
                c1.postid = post.postid
        ) And
        Exists (
            Select
                'x'
            From
                post_category As c2
            Where
                c2.categoryid In (130, 3, 4, 5) And
                c2.postid = post.postid
        ) And
        post.approve = 1
    Order By
        post.fixed Desc,
        post.date Desc
    Limit
        0, 7
  ) As lim
      Join
    post AS p
        On lim.id = p.id 
      Left Join
    post_plus As pp
        On lim.id = pp.news_id
Order By
    p.fixed Desc,
    p.date Desc  ;
```

Comment: You guys are awesome! (0.06 sec)